# r8169 Realtek ethernet module doesn't detect device after kernel upgrade >5.4.0-48-generic Is it a bug?

Tags: networking, kernel, 20.04, realtek

On my server, the on-board realtek ethernet card is not detected after a kernel upgrade from `5.4.0-48-generic` to `5.4.0-52` (and `5.4.0-51`).  Oddly though on a gaming rig with the identical motherboard, network card revision, and bios version, running KDE Neon with the same ubuntu kernel (`5.4.0-52-generic`), it works fine.

lshw:
`description: Motherboard`
`product: X470 GAMING PLUS (MS-7B79)`
`vendor: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd`
dmidecode -s bios-version: `A.50`
lspci -nnv:
`18:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)`
`Kernel driver in use: r8169`
lsb_release: `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS focal`
uname: `Linux 5.4.0-52-generic x86_64`

`dmesg |grep 8169` (5.4.0-48):

```
[    0.000000] kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic root=UUID=b33c1eb8-59d7-479e-977c-cff95aff44e9 ro nomodeset
[    0.000000] kernel: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic root=UUID=b33c1eb8-59d7-479e-977c-cff95aff44e9 ro nomodeset
[    0.703027] kernel: libphy: r8169: probed
[    0.703613] kernel: r8169 0000:18:00.0 eth0: RTL8168h/8111h, 00:d8:61:10:37:54, XID 541, IRQ 65
[    0.704030] kernel: r8169 0000:18:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    0.739820] kernel: r8169 0000:18:00.0 p1p1: renamed from eth0
[    7.140575] kernel: Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-1800:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-1800:00, irq=IGNORE)
[    7.253204] kernel: r8169 0000:18:00.0 p1p1: Link is Down
[   10.768877] kernel: r8169 0000:18:00.0 p1p1: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
```

`dmesg |grep 8169` (5.4.0-52):

```
[    0.000000] kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic root=UUID=b33c1eb8-59d7-479e-977c-cff95aff44e9 ro nomodeset
[    0.000000] kernel: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic root=UUID=b33c1eb8-59d7-479e-977c-cff95aff44e9 ro nomodeset
[    0.705941] kernel: libphy: r8169: probed
[    0.706490] kernel: r8169 0000:18:00.0 eth0: RTL8168h/8111h, 00:d8:61:10:37:54, XID 541, IRQ 62
[    0.706876] kernel: r8169 0000:18:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
```

The `rmmod r8169 && modprobe r8169` realtek workaround did not work this time.

Should I file a bug or did a distro network config change happen in Ubuntu Server but not in KDE Neon?

Edit: **Additional Information**

I'll also try the `r8168-dkms` package and update the question with the results if I get a chance to take the server down again.

`# modinfo r8169 | grep -i 10ec` (5.4.0-48):

```
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00003000sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008125sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008169sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008168sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008167sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008161sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008136sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008129sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00002600sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00002502sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

`sudo lshw -C network` (5.4.0-48):

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:18:00.0
       logical name: p1p1
       version: 15
       serial: 00:d8:61:10:37:54
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:34 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe604000-fe604fff memory:fe600000-fe603fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: vnet0
       serial: fe:54:00:cb:bd:03
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:b3:57:96
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: br0
       serial: 74:d4:35:53:6e:59
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.16.11 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:3 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:b3:57:96
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces` (5.4.0-48):

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0

#iface eth0 inet static
#       address 192.168.16.10
#       netmask 255.255.255.0
#       gateway 192.168.16.2

#auto p1p1
iface p1p1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.16.11
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.16.255
        network 192.168.16.0
        gateway 192.168.16.2
        bridge_ports p1p1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 3
        bridge_maxwait 0
        post-up ip link set br0 address 74:d4:35:53:6e:59
        up route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 192.168.20.80

iface br0:0 inet static
        address 192.168.16.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` (5.4.0-48): `No such file or directory`

Comment: Try using the `r8168-dkms` driver. Report back.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `lspci -nn` and `modinfo r8169 | grep -i 10ec`

Comment: Your `lspci` command shows that the ethernet controller is at rev 15. Compare that to the other computer that works.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, and solves the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Your /etc/network/interfaces file just doesn't look right, as does the ethernet interface named p1p1. Have you renamed that port somewhere else, or made any other code changes? Temporarily comment out ALL of the active statements except for the first two for the "lo" device, reboot, and see if the ethernet port comes back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema appreciate the enthusiasm but it works with 5.4.0-48 and troubleshooting the network requires me to stand on a chair in a closet while typing :) so I'm gonna wait until a few more kernel versions are released and if it persists then I'll try some of your suggestions (r8168-dkms, clean-up /etc/network/interfaces)  Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Fair enough. Do consider the BIOS update, as newer kernels require current BIOSs. Cheers!

Comment: @heynnema thanks again for your help.  The issue is gone in `5.4.0-65-generic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The issue no longer occurs in `5.4.0-65-generic`.  As suspected it was a change in the kernel or r8168 module that maybe was fixed or reverted.

The only difference now is the device is called `eth0` again instead of `p1p1`

Answer (score 1):

**r8168**

Try the `r8168-dkms` driver.

**BIOS**

MSI X470 GAMING PLUS

You have BIOS version A.50.

There's a newer BIOS available, version A.H0, dated 6/16/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/X470-GAMING-PLUS).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: yeah i don't have the latest bios.  Interesting though how a gaming rig with the identical motherboard, bios version, and kernel works fine.  The only difference is KDE Neon vs Ubuntu server.  If I get a chance to take the server down again and the firmware update fixes it, I'll accept the answer.  thanks

Comment: @codywohlers Status please...

Comment: I haven't had a chance to take the server offline.  I just apt-marked it at 5.4.0-48 while I get caught back up.